# DNS redirection while keeping the same domain name with CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-cloudfront, cname

I'm currently hosting a React website through AWS CloudFront. I have the CloudFront URL, ex: `http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net` but I want to use the distribution with my domain name. I am using Google Domains at the current moment. I've looked into CNAME records and ALIAS records (Google Domains currently doesn't support ALIAS) but still haven't figured out a solution. At the same time, I'm trying to reduce downtime for the site, so this is a bit tricky because I'm trying to minimize experimentation.

---

**Here's what I've tried:**

CNAME: `www -> xxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net`

Result: caused website to not load

CNAME: `@ -> xxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net`

Result: Google Domains doesn't let you do this!

I also tried Google's "Synthetic Records" for redirection, but as I expected that just redirects to the CloudFront domain whenever I enter my domain.

---

I know that AWS Route 53 would be a valid option *except* that they don't support '.app' domains for some reason.

I've included the domain CNAME and SSL certificate on CloudFront, but I'm confused about what I'm doing wrong as for the DNS info.

[image: AWS CloudFront Info]

Has anyone had experience setting up a CloudFront website for their own domains using Google Domains? I've done a bunch of research on this but for some reason haven't found any results that have helped me.

Comment: DNS records should not have the `http://` part, only hostname

Comment: @DusanBajic My mistake when writing this question, I have tried using only the hostname for the DNS records and there was no success there either